# keeping a div at the centre of page when resizing

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to keep my div centred when a page resizes. Like this for example https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login

But when I resize it currently resizes the whole div. Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "formwrap">
        <form action = "./PHP/main_login.php" method = "post">
            <input type = "text" name = "email" id = "email" placeholder = "Email"/><br>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password" placeholder = "Password"/><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submitlogin" id = "submitbut" value = "Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper{
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;
    float: center;
}

#formwrap{
    width:100%;
    background-color: #383838;
    float: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to keep the div and the contents within it the same size while decreasing the horizontal screen size until I call a media query. All help much appreciated

Comment: Instead of defining a percentage passing on the outer parent, use a fix width for the child instead. And there isn't such a thing as `float: center`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Set a width for you wrapper and give it `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Refer to this: [How to keep a floating div centered on window resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956671/how-to-keep-a-floating-div-centered-on-window-resize-jquery-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place it in a container div with `text-align:center` and add `display:inline-block` to it:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block;">


    </div>
</div>
```

Then your div will be at the center of page and its with won't change by resizing but with its content or the width given to it.

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mLrym9qz/)

Comment: Please add an explanation of a description to your answer.

Comment: well I always add the code and then the explanation ;)

Comment: OK then it's no problem

Comment: I also added a demo please have a look

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ogs0mfmn/

```
#wrapper{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#formwrap{
 margin-left: 50%;
 margin-right: 50%;
 background-color: #383838;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a width to your #formwrapper and give it `margin: 0 auto`

```
#wrapper{
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right: 30%;
    float: center; background-color: blue
    height: 100vh; width: 40%;
}

#formwrap{
    width:200px;
    background-color: #383838;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL9w1v7q/)